# How to display multi page TIFF with PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, tiff

I need to display a multi page tiff file with PyQt
from the search in the internet they say that Qt doesn't support
multi page TIFF.
My code only shows the first page:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,  parent = None):
        super(Dialog,  self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(1280, 1024)
        masterLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.pictureLabel = QLabel()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.pictureLabel)
        self.status_Label = QLabel('100')
        masterLayout.addLayout(mainLayout)      
        self.img_refresh()

    def img_refresh(self):
        imagem = QPixmap('image.tif')
        myScaledPixmap = imagem.scaled(1280,1024) 
        self.pictureLabel.setPixmap(myScaledPixmap)
        self.setWindowTitle('test')

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Dialog()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Using [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) is also an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tifffile package which also supports multipage tiffs. They can be converted to numpy arrays which can be converted to QImages with qimage2ndarray and these can be converted to QPixmaps.

Information about the tifffile package:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tifffile

Documentation of the qimage2ndarray package:
http://hmeine.github.io/qimage2ndarray/

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultiPageTIFFViewerPyQt https://github.com/marcel-goldschen-ohm/MultiPageTIFFViewerPyQt/tree/master which is pretty well written.